# What’s the difference between rasterization and rendering?

Tags: rendering, rasterizing

Can anybody explain how rendering differs from rasterization especially in the context of font rendering (why not font rasterization)?

Can rendering be called a special technique (like greyscale rendering and subpixel rendering) before the rasterizer rasterizes the image?

Comment: Is this an exam question or homework?

Comment: Wikipedia is pretty clear about that.
Rasterisation is the process of converting vector data to image data whereas rendering handles models,lightning model ,texturing ... 
For example rasterisation of vector does not use a lightning model generally

Answer (score 8):

*Rendering* is a broad term that generally means transforming computer-readable information, for example objects in a 3d scene, to one or more images.

*Rasterization* is a more specific term that typically means the process of transforming a vector (curve based) image to a rasterized (pixel based) image.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering involves performing the calculations for vectors and shape geometry for the elements to be drawn.

Rasterizing involves converting the rendered vectors and shapes into pixel bit maps for display.